# callIntenet is not working, i have no idea how to fix this.

Tags: android

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqYtw.jpg)

the error msg says:
Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException` less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection looks at Android API calls and ensures that the correct type of resource is passed to an int-parameter expecting resources of a given type; it checks that APIs which expect an RGB color integer are passed actual colors rather than color resources; it checks that APIs which require a certain permission have the permission declared in the manifest; it checks that parameters expected to fall within a given range actually do; it checks that results of certain method calls are looked at by the caller, and so on.

code:
     Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                               callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
                                               startActivity(callIntent);
     image:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From API 23, It is necessary to check permission even after declared in manifest.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
```

Refer http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Starting on Marshmallow, you need to check for permissions first. ACTION_CALL requires a CALL_PHONE permission. Instead of ACTION_CALL, maybe you can use ACTION_DIAL for it does not need any permission. Itt will not call directly the number you specified but open the user's default dialer app with the number specified.